Can I "extract" python virtualenv site-packages from one machine to another to avoid using pip?
I wish to create python virtual environment on different Linux machines that do have python-venv module installed but no pip, and no internet access.
My idea is to create python virtual-env using python3 -m venv --without-pip my-venv-name for python3 or python -m virtualenv --no-pip my-venv-name for python 2.7, which will generate an empty virtual environment, my question is if I'm using the same python major and minor, and copy pasting the site-packages from a pre-prepared same python major & minor virtual env and expect things to work correctly?
important to mention that the packages will be installed in the original python-virtualenv using the same platform_tags.

No need to create a virtual env on the target machine. As long as the absolute path stays the same, I think you can just pack and unpack the whole virtualenv folder

since the python executables are softlinks, in some machine they got broken

A more robust way would be to download the dist files required for populating the virtual environment, and recreating it from scratch on another machine, using these dist files. Example: imagine you have a requirements.txt with the dependencies you need:
# requirements.txt
requests==2.32.3  # etc

On the first machine where you have internet:
$ mkdir dist
$ pip download pip -r requirements.txt --dest dist

You have now downloaded dist files for pip and your project requirements. Copy the dist directory contents to the other machine you have no internet on. Now on this machine, run:
$ python -m venv --without-pip my-venv-name
$ source my-venv-name/bin/activate
(my-venv-name) $ python dist/pip-24.2-py3-none-any.whl/pip install \
  -r requirements.txt \
  --no-index \
  --find-links=dist \
  --disable-pip-version-check

This will work because:

No need to install pip, simply using the script from pip's dist wheel is enough.
No need to have internet since --no-index will instruct pip to ignore PyPI and --find-links=dist will tell pip where to search for the packages to install from instead. --disable-pip-version-check is optional and will speed up the installation since pip will not try and reach the internet for self-update checks.


I have done a similar things. I fiddled with the pip download command to get exactly what I wanted, copied to another machine, then was able to pip install --no-index --find-links=downloads/.
